# How To allow useragnet and block others using htaccess

Tags: php, curl

I want to block all other UserAgent came from outside and access only mine and access it using curl php file

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1 SV2 SERVERS Chromium)
```

I tried this code to block  others and access only my UserAgent

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1 SV2 SERVERS Chromium)
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

blocked okay
but when I tried to make curl php request

```
    $getdetails = "https://domain.php/file.php";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $getdetails);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1 SV2 SERVERS Chromium)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
    $content = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $content;
    echo "<script>window.location.href='./FOLDER';</script>";exit();
```

it's given me forbidden as I'm blocked because UserAgent

Comment: You know it's trivial to spoof the user agent value, yes? In fact your cURL code is actually doing that exact thing. So if you think this will be secure, think again. If you want only certain people to access the application, apply some proper authentication.

Comment: actually i don't want it for scam/spam purpose do the guys who know answer they will if you think it's trivial then think again :D

Comment: BTW This useragent is fake and i request to my website i hide the domain with domain.com so idc

Comment: Ok. But remember the mantra "security by obscurity is not security", when it bites you in the a** later

Comment: Anyway I could be wrong but I don't see anything in your rewrite rule which would cause a 403 Forbiddden response. Are you sure that's related to the htaccess changes? Remove the htaccess temporarrily, and see if you get the same result or not from the cURL code.

Comment: `i don't want it for scam/spam purpose`...I never suggested that you did. Not sure why you mentioned that.

Comment: idk I feel like you're trying to say this, but you don't want to

Comment: I don't know why you would think that? I'm not saying that you're trying to scam anything. Trust me, if I think something, I will say it - I don't play word games :-). And anyway how could you be scamming anything with this code? Your code is an attempt to protect your application from other people. My point was that it's a risky way to do your security. If _someone else_ manages to find out, or guess, the user-agent to use, then they can easily bypass this rule. I suppose since you've invented the UA value it's a bit like a password...but then why not just use proper password authentication?

Comment: Listen, chief
All I'm trying to do is to close the view of any file inside the folder
And I want to stop anyone who comes from outside to view the files
Knowing that I want to give access for only the people who have my useragent to view the files only this and that's by php

Comment: Well I've just asked you to do a test to verify if the htaccess is actually causing the Forbidden error. Done that yet?

Comment: But either way, this isn't a recommended approach to blocking access to things. Apache has the ability to set HTTP password authentication, certifiicate authentication etc etc which is how you're supposed to do this kind of thing, to get proper security. I'm not really sure why you chose the user-agent string approach...it's not intended as a security mechanism, and as I've said twice already, people can (and will) find ways to eliminate its usefulness for that purpose). Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: i did in the php that header location redirect to  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 i t's gived me another user agent

Comment: Sorry it's unclear exactly what that means in practice. But it didn't cause a 403, is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes it didnot said 403 when i deleted htaccess file

Comment: i want to send request from file.php to folder and if request didn't happen from file.php its goes die(); but idk how

Comment: Simplest way, is you could use a secret API key that you put into a HTTP header, and have the receiving PHP file or the htaccess check that. Similar to the UA string idea but a bit more secure as you'd use a GUID or something which is much harder to guess. Or you could use password authentication in Apache as I mentioned (which is well documented, I don't need to explain that to you because it's quite easy to research).

Comment: Although htaccess is powerful and technically closer to a "front line of defense", I would also encourage you to just do this in PHP. It is easier to test and debug, and also easier to change in the future. You can use a user agent if you really want, but I agree that a custom HTTP header might just be easier, which is what ADyson is suggesting.

Comment: I want to block if request came to folder without the header 'apikey' without using php on folder , just htaccess

Comment: Then you can use HTTP authentication. API Key isn't difficult though.